# Как обьеденить модули вебпака через функцию merge?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, webpack

Через функцию merge, в случае если версия вебпака development, я пытаюсь добавить к нему только к этом случае файл сервера. Пишет ошибку. Он пишет, что не правильные типы, но я указала, одинаковый тип в обоих интерфейсах

Аргумент типа "IdevServer" нельзя назначить параметру типа "IgetConfig".
Свойство "entry" отсутствует в типе "IdevServer" и является обязательным в типе "IgetConfig".

```
return merge(mainConfig, serverTuning);
```

файл dev.config.ts

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    port: 3000,
  },
};
```

файл webpack.config.ts

```
 import { merge } from 'webpack-merge';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
import { PlatformPath } from 'path';

const path: PlatformPath = require('path');

interface IdevServer {
  devServer: {
    port: number;
  };
}

const serverTuning: IdevServer = require('./dev.config');

const test = 'main';
const ROOT_DIRECTORY = path.resolve(__dirname, '..');

interface IgetConfig {
  entry: {
    main: string[];
  };
  devServer?: {
    port: number;
  };
}

const getConfig = (mode): IgetConfig => {
  const isProduction = mode === 'production';
  const isDevelopment = mode === 'development';

  return {
    entry: {
      [test]: ['./src/index.js'],
    },
  };
};

module.exports = (env, { mode }) => {
  const mainConfig = getConfig(mode);

  if (mode === 'development') {
    return merge(mainConfig, serverTuning);
  }

  return mainConfig;
};


module.exports = (env, { mode }) => {
  const mainConfig = getConfig(mode);

  if (mode === 'development') {
    return merge(mainConfig, serverTuning);
  }

  return mainConfig;
};
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Отступлюсь от вопроса и хочу посоветовать вам расширение "Error Lens".

Comment: установила, пишет интереснее встроенного, но исправить не получилось